# How to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the cokurtosis matrix?

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues, kurtosis, tensor

Kurtosis is the fourth statistical moment of a random variable's distribution. Unlike the variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$, which had a shape of $p\times p$, the **kurtosis-cokurtosis matrix** is shaped $p\times p^3$.

For bivariate data, $p=2$, the cokurtosis matrix is shaped $2\times 2^3 = 2\times 8$,
$$K = 
\begin{pmatrix}
k_{1,1,1,1} & k_{1,1,1,2} & k_{1,1,2,1} & k_{1,1,2,2} & k_{1,2,1,1} & k_{1,2,1,2} & k_{1,2,2,1} & k_{1,2,2,2} \\
k_{2,1,1,1} & k_{2,1,1,2} & s_{2,1,2,1} & k_{2,1,2,2} & k_{2,2,1,1} & k_{2,2,1,2} & k_{2,2,2,1} & k_{2,2,2,2} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with only $5$ of the $16$ elements being distinct. which of the elements are kurtosis values rather than cokurtosis values?

Does this matrix have a characteristic polynomial for getting its eigenvalues and eigenvectors? If so, how to find them.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583938/do-non-square-matrices-have-eigenvalues) suggests I should be looking for singular values and singular vectors instead of eigenvalues and eigenvectors since the matrix is non-square.

Comment: Non-square matrices don't have characteristic polynomials, nor do they have eigenvectors and eigenvalues. You should change the question to: "How to find the singular values and singular vectors" instead, and you can do this numerically by taking the SVD of $K$.

Comment: the singular values and singular vectors lead to the matrix's eigenvalues and eigenvectors though?

Comment: Not quite. The matrix doesn't have eigenvalues/vectors, so it doesn't make sense to talk about the singular values/vectors as "leading you" to something that doesn't exist. However, you can think of singular values as being a generalization of eigenvalues. What are you actually trying to do with this matrix $K$? It might be that you can use the singular values/vectors for your purpose.